# Was fügt hier „gegenüber“ hinzu?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Ich habe diesen Satz im Buch gelesen:

> Tom erwähnte seine Zweifel Mary gegenüber nie. Er wollte nicht, dass sie es falsch auffasste.

Wieso hat der Author *gegenüber* hier benutzt? 
Was wäre der Unterschied, wenn man einfach sagt „Tom erwähnte seine Zweifel Mary nie“, ohne gegenüber verwendet zu haben?

Ich kenne das Wort im Sinne von *towards* oder *opposite*.

Comment: *Erwähnen* kann man nicht mit einem indirekten Objekt (Dativobjekt) benutzen. *Mary* ist also kein indirektes Objekt. *Mary gegenüber* ist eine adverbiale Bestimmung, die mit der Postposition *gegenüber* gebildet ist. *Towards* ist hier tatsächlich eine passende Übersetzung; allerdings wäre in diesem Fall *to* noch besser. (Wenn man *erwähnen* mit *mention* übersetzt.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Würde man das *gegenüber* weglassen, wäre der Satz schlicht falsch.

Die Person, die die Bemerkung eines anderen hört, wird immer mit *gegenüber* verbunden.

Das kann man sich bildlich vorstellen:
Zwei Personen, der Sprecher und der Zuhörer, sitzen sich bei einer Unterhaltung *gegenüber* (auch wenn das in der konkreten Situation vielleicht nicht so ist) und auch der Gesprächspartner wird im Deutschen oft als *Gegenüber* bezeichnet (vgl. engl. *counterpart*: auch hier ist das *gegen-* enthalten).

Wenn man aus irgendeinem Grund *gegenüber* nicht verwenden will, kann der Informationsempfänger dennoch nicht ohne Verbindung stehen, eine mögliche Formulierung wäre z.B.:

> Tom erwähnte seine Zweifel *bei* Mary nie.

Allerdings entfällt damit die Eindeutigkeit, dass Mary der Gesprächspartner ist, der Satz könnte dann auch die räumliche Bedeutung von „in ihrem Haus“/„in ihrer Wohnung“ o.ä. haben.

Comment: _Gegenüber_ fungiert hier als Postposition. Es kann aber auch Präposition sein: *Tom erwähnte seine Zweifel nie gegenüber Mary.* (Wortstellung zur Sicherheit, damit es nicht als _Zweifel gegenüber Mary_ = _Zweifel an Mary_ interpretiert werden kann.)

Comment: Postpositionen sind im Deutschen relativ selten, aber im Englischen noch seltener. Die einzigen englischen Beispiele, die ich auf die Schnelle gefunden hab, sind *ago, aside, notwithstanding*. Letztere hat wie *gegenüber* die Eigenschaft, dass man sie auch als Präposition benutzen kann.

Answer (score 4):

Das Problem liegt schlicht und ergreifend darin, dass *erwähnen* ein transitives Verb ist, das nur ein Objekt erlaubt. Es heißt *etwas erwähnen* und ist damit anders als etwa *jemandem etwas sagen.*

> Tom erwähnt seine Zweifel.
>   Tom erwähnt Mary.
>   Tom erwähnt seine Zweifel und Mary.

Wenn ich unbedingt in jemandes Gegenwart etwas erwähnen möchte, dann muss ich dazu eine Adverbialkonstruktion wählen – und nichts anderes ist *jemandem gegenüber* in diesem Fall. Allerdings hat sich die Verwendung *jemandem gegenüber etwas erwähnen* bereits so eingeschliffen, dass in ein paar Jahrzehnten die beiden vielleicht als zusammengehörig empfunden werden, und *erwähnen* dadurch bitransitiv wird.